# Catch errors in asyncio.ensure_future

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-asyncio

I have this code:

```
try:
    asyncio.ensure_future(data_streamer.sendByLatest())
except ValueError as e:
    logging.debug(repr(e))
```

`data_streamer.sendByLatest()` can raise a `ValueError`, but it is not caught.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ensure_future` - just creates `Task` and return immediately. You should await for created task to get it's result (including case when it raises exception):

```
import asyncio


async def test():
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    raise ValueError('123')


async def main():    
    try:
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(test())  # Task aren't finished here yet 
        await task  # Here we await for task finished and here exception would be raised 
    except ValueError as e:
        print(repr(e))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
ValueError('123',)
```

In case you aren't planning to await task immediately after you created it, you can await it later (to know how it has finished):

```
async def main():    
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(test())
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    # At this moment task finished with exception,
    # but we didn't retrieved it's exception.
    # We can do it just awaiting task:
    try:
        await task  
    except ValueError as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

Output is same:

```
ValueError('123',)
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know also how to catch exceptions with `call_soon_threadsafe()`?

Comment: @MarcoSulla sorry, I don't know. One way I see is to use wrapper to handle exception in callback: http://pastebin.com/rNyTWMBk but I don't know if it's common way to do it.